# Clicking a button within a specific row

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I currently have a test that adds an entry to the table below, generating a random location name and value. I'm now trying to click on the edit icon within the table.

[image: Table]

I can find the correct location name cell using-

```
string editButton = "//td[text(),'"+locationName+ "'];
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(editButton)).Click();
```

But not sure how to click on the Edit button from here?

HTML for the button is-

```
<tr id="officeRechargeGrid_DXDataRow1" class="dxgvDataRow_Office2010Silver" style="">
    <td class="dxgvCommandColumn_Office2010Silver dxgv" align="center"><a class="dxbButton_Office2010Silver dxgvCommandColumnItem_Office2010Silver dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys" data-args="[['StartEdit',1],1]" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn3" href="javascript:;" style="font-size: 0pt;"><img title="Edit" class="dx-vam" src="/Images/editgray.png" alt="Edit" style="height:16px;width:16px;" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn3Img"></a><script id="dxss_1145064087" type="text/javascript" data-executed="true">
```

HTML for the table is-

```
//-->
</script></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></td><td id="officeRechargeGrid_col2" class="dxgvHeader_Office2010Silver" onmousedown="ASPx.GHeaderMouseDown('officeRechargeGrid', this, event);" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>Location</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span><img class="dxGridView_gvHeaderFilter_Office2010Silver dxgv__hfb dx-vam" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_37-Z658g" alt="[Filter]" style="cursor:default;"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></td><td id="officeRechargeGrid_col3" class="dxgvHeader_Office2010Silver" onmousedown="ASPx.GHeaderMouseDown('officeRechargeGrid', this, event);" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;border-right-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>Assumed Volume</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span><img class="dxGridView_gvHeaderFilter_Office2010Silver dxgv__hfb dx-vam" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_37-Z658g" alt="[Filter]" style="cursor:default;"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></td>
    </tr><tr id="officeRechargeGrid_DXFilterRow" class="dxgvFilterRow_Office2010Silver">
        <td class="dxgvCommandColumn_Office2010Silver dxgv" align="center">&nbsp;</td><td class="dxgv"><table class="dxeTextBoxSys dxeTextBox_Office2010Silver dxeTextBoxDefaultWidthSys" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol2" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="dxic" style="width:100%;"><input class="dxeEditArea_Office2010Silver dxeEditAreaSys" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol2_I" name="officeRechargeGrid$DXFREditorcol2" onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol2')" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol2')" onchange="ASPx.EValueChanged('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol2')" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><script id="dxss_334903315" type="text/javascript" data-executed="true">
<!--
ASPx.AddDisabledItems('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol2',[[['dxeDisabled_Office2010Silver'],[''],['','I']]]);

var dxo = new ASPxClientTextBox('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol2');
dxo.InitGlobalVariable('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol2');
dxo.uniqueID = 'officeRechargeGrid$DXFREditorcol2';
dxo.ValueChanged.AddHandler(function(s, event) { ASPx.GVFilterChanged('officeRechargeGrid',s); });
dxo.KeyDown.AddHandler(function(s, event) { ASPx.GVFilterKeyPress('officeRechargeGrid',s,event); });
dxo.RequireStyleDecoration();
dxo.styleDecoration.AddStyle('F','dxeFocused_Office2010Silver','');
dxo.AfterCreate();

//-->
</script></td><td class="dxgv" style="text-align:Right;border-right-width:0px;"><table class="dxeTextBoxSys dxeTextBox_Office2010Silver dxeTextBoxDefaultWidthSys" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol3" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="dxic" style="width:100%;"><input class="dxeEditArea_Office2010Silver dxeEditAreaSys" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol3_I" name="officeRechargeGrid$DXFREditorcol3" onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol3')" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol3')" onchange="ASPx.EValueChanged('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol3')" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><script id="dxss_1037231823" type="text/javascript" data-executed="true">
<!--
ASPx.AddDisabledItems('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol3',[[['dxeDisabled_Office2010Silver'],[''],['','I']]]);

var dxo = new ASPxClientTextBox('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol3');
dxo.InitGlobalVariable('officeRechargeGrid_DXFREditorcol3');
dxo.uniqueID = 'officeRechargeGrid$DXFREditorcol3';
dxo.ValueChanged.AddHandler(function(s, event) { ASPx.GVFilterChanged('officeRechargeGrid',s); });
dxo.KeyDown.AddHandler(function(s, event) { ASPx.GVFilterKeyPress('officeRechargeGrid',s,event); });
dxo.RequireStyleDecoration();
dxo.styleDecoration.AddStyle('F','dxeFocused_Office2010Silver','');
dxo.AfterCreate();

//-->
</script></td>
    </tr><tr id="officeRechargeGrid_DXDataRow0" class="dxgvDataRow_Office2010Silver" style="">
        <td class="dxgvCommandColumn_Office2010Silver dxgv" align="center"><a class="dxbButton_Office2010Silver dxgvCommandColumnItem_Office2010Silver dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys" data-args="[['StartEdit',0],1]" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn1" href="javascript:;" style="font-size: 0pt;"><img title="Edit" class="dx-vam" src="/Images/editgray.png" alt="Edit" style="height:16px;width:16px;" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn1Img"></a><script id="dxss_1182543207" type="text/javascript" data-executed="true">
<!--
ASPx.AddDisabledItems('officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn1',[[['dxbDisabled_Office2010Silver'],[''],[''],['','TC']]]);

//-->
</script><a class="dxbButton_Office2010Silver dxgvCommandColumnItem_Office2010Silver dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys" data-args="[['Delete',0],1]" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn2" href="javascript:;" style="font-size: 0pt;"><img title="Delete" class="dx-vam" src="/Images/delete.png" alt="Delete" style="height:16px;width:16px;" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn2Img"></a><script id="dxss_2131039704" type="text/javascript" data-executed="true">
<!--
ASPx.AddDisabledItems('officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn2',[[['dxbDisabled_Office2010Silver'],[''],[''],['','TC']]]);

//-->
</script></td><td class="dxgv">TAHPOYOWAG</td><td class="dxgv" style="border-right-width:0px;" align="right">49,554.00</td>
    </tr><tr id="officeRechargeGrid_DXDataRow1" class="dxgvDataRow_Office2010Silver dxgvLVR" style="">
        <td class="dxgvCommandColumn_Office2010Silver dxgv" style="border-bottom-width:0px;" align="center"><a class="dxbButton_Office2010Silver dxgvCommandColumnItem_Office2010Silver dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys" data-args="[['StartEdit',1],1]" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn3" href="javascript:;" style="font-size: 0pt;"><img title="Edit" class="dx-vam" src="/Images/editgray.png" alt="Edit" style="height:16px;width:16px;" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn3Img"></a><script id="dxss_1145064087" type="text/javascript" data-executed="true">
<!--
ASPx.AddDisabledItems('officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn3',[[['dxbDisabled_Office2010Silver'],[''],[''],['','TC']]]);

//-->
</script><a class="dxbButton_Office2010Silver dxgvCommandColumnItem_Office2010Silver dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys" data-args="[['Delete',1],1]" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn4" href="javascript:;" style="font-size: 0pt;"><img title="Delete" class="dx-vam" src="/Images/delete.png" alt="Delete" style="height:16px;width:16px;" id="officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn4Img"></a><script id="dxss_511888854" type="text/javascript" data-executed="true">
<!--
ASPx.AddDisabledItems('officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn4',[[['dxbDisabled_Office2010Silver'],[''],[''],['','TC']]]);

//-->
</script></td><td class="dxgv" style="border-bottom-width:0px;">JKFZICCPJA</td><td class="dxgv" style="border-right-width:0px;border-bottom-width:0px;" align="right">76,646.00</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Could you share the HTML code of the buttons?

Comment: @Anand Just added it :)

Comment: What is that `locationName` which you are trying to pass to the `xpath`?

Comment: @DebanjanB The locationName is the string that appears in the "Location" column.

Comment: What is the value of `locationName` in the _HTML_ which you have shared?

Comment: @AutomatedTester can you please give us the code of the whole table block so we can work on a solution that will work with all rows?

Comment: @Thodoris Koskinopoulos Just added this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[child::img[@title='Edit'] and parent::td[following-sibling::td[text()='" + locationName + "']]]")).Click();
```

Comment: Just tried this but an exception was thrown - {"Unable to locate element: //a[child::img[@title='Edit'] and parent::td[following-sibling::td[text()=RDVDSOLHYF]]]"}

Comment: Show full html row including location column. Not only edit button.

Comment: Have just added the html for the entire table, hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, I've missed apostrophes around locationName. I've corrected my answer. Try now

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You have not given us the ID from the main table (to narrow down the HTML), so just search all the `tr` on the page.

Then, get all rows from the table.

```
var rows = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
```

In that collection, you will search for all the columns, and narrow down your results to a specific row with your `locationName`.

```
var desiredRow = rows.Where(row => row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[1] == locationName);
```

Now that you have your desired row, search in that row to find the edit button (I can see there is only one anchor, so easiest search, is by `tagname`)

```
deriredRow.FindElement(By.TagName("a")).Click();
```

If you create a function for the sole purpose of clicking the edit button, it goes like this:

```
public void ClickEdit(string locationName)
{
    driver.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"))
        .Where(row => row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[1] == locationName).Single()
        .FindElement(By.TagName("a")).Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try identifying the Edit buttons first and save them in a list. Then click on each of them in turn using loop.

```
List<WebElement> trList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='Your table ID here']/tr/td/a/img"));
                          (or)
List<WebElement> trList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Edit']"));
            for(int i=0;i<trList.size();i++){
                trList.get(i).click();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To to click on the **Edit** *button* within the table you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='dxbButton_Office2010Silver dxgvCommandColumnItem_Office2010Silver dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys' and @id='officeRechargeGrid_DXCBtn3']")).Click();
```